# Prove that if $\{a_n\}$ converges to $a$ and $|a|<1$ that $\{a_n^n\}$ converges to $0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I get the idea that since $|a|<1$ then for large enough $n$ $a_n<1$ so that when you take the $n^{th}$ power the sequence values become very small. I am struggling to write out the actual $\epsilon-N$ proof however. My inequalities never yield what I need and I keep making mistakes and coming up with inequalities that are not even true.

For example I know that I need $|a_n^n|<\epsilon$ for any given $\epsilon$. Working backwards I could get this if $|a_n|<\epsilon^{1/n}$ but this won't happen because the $a_n^{'s}$ are all close to $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n\log|a_{n}|\rightarrow-\infty$ since $\log|a_{n}|\rightarrow\log|a|<0$, so $|a_{n}|^{n}=\exp(n\log|a_{n}|)\rightarrow 0$ and hence $a_{n}^{n}\rightarrow 0$.

**$\epsilon$-argument:**

Given $\epsilon>0$, since $|a|<1$, we can pick an $\eta>0$ so small such that $|a|+\eta <1$. We may take an $N$ so large such that $(|a|+\eta)^{N}<\epsilon$. For the $\eta>0$, we can choose some $n_{0}\geq N$ such that $|a_{n}-a|<\eta$ for all $n\geq n_{0}$, so $|a_{n}|<|a|+\eta$ and hence $|a_{n}|^{n}\leq|a_{n}|^{N}<(|a|+\eta)^{N}<\epsilon$ for all such $n$.

Comment: Unfortunately the only tools I have to work with are things such as monotone convergence and the basic definition of a limit of a sequence. I am purposefully asked to not used advanced limit calculation tools.

Comment: Okay, no problem, I can write you the $\epsilon$-argument.

Comment: You may take a look now.

Comment: Thank you. I see that your argument works but some of the steps seem unmotivated. Not that that is a bad thing it is simply I don't see the motivation for them, primarily your choosing an $\eta$ so that $|a|+\eta<1$.

Comment: Just try to do something without it, and I find that it is struggle to conclude: We expect something like $|a_{n}|^{n}\leq|a_{n}|^{N}<\epsilon$, but how? Okay, if we simply let $|a_{n}-a|<\epsilon$, we have that $|a_{n}|<|a|+\epsilon$, then $|a_{n}|^{N}<(|a|+\epsilon)^{N}$, but the question is, $|a|+\epsilon$ may be a little bigger than $1$, then it fails to conclude that $(|a|+\epsilon)^{N}<\epsilon$. If it were that $|a|+\epsilon<1$, then it goes through. Actually one may consider only for all small $\epsilon>0$ such that $\epsilon<1-|a|$.

Comment: Then for any other $\epsilon>0$ such that $\epsilon\geq 1-|a|$, you need to run through the argument again. To skip this double reasoning, just fix the $\epsilon>0$ first, and we let $\eta>0$ to do the job as a candidate for small positive number such that $|a|+\eta<1$.